# Dataloader upsert error

Tags: data-loader, upsert

While I am doing an upsert operation in data loader, I am getting an error as:

> unable to obtain access to these records.

What could be a possible reason for this?

Comment: Can you explain your question briefly? What are you trying to upload and what is the relationship.

Comment: Could you please add more details

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what **profile** you are upserting using dataloader, check:

`Setup -> Manage Users -> Profiles -> <Profile you are using to data load> (I'm assuming you are using the System Administrator profile?) -> Object Settings`

Depending on which `object` you are data loading with, check the **object permissions** and make sure you have Read, Create & Edit Permissions.

Comment: I am using system admin profile and i am inserting to custom object which has all permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bulk API in dataloader,  check the box `Enable serial mode for Bulk API`.

If not, try again later. You can get this error if the records you are updating are locked for some reason.